# Using arcpy.SearchCursor SQL clause?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I got a table with the name Predios

like this:

```
OBJECTID   PRM_IDENTIFICA

1          4030200606130

2          403020060615

3          40302006011700
```

Can I use search cursor to find the records when the PRM_IDENTIFICA len its <> 14.???

Right now i got:

```
import arcpy

tabla="C:/Users/jaguero/Desktop/validacion tabla/Valid.gdb/Predios"

rows=arcpy.SearchCursor(tabla)

row=rows.next()

while row:

print len(row.PRM_IDENTIFICA)

row=rows.next()
```

giving me this:

```
13

12

14
```

What if I want only as a result the records when the len is <> from 14 ?

Comment: How does your top example (`1 4030200606130` etc.) relate to your bottom example (`13` etc.)?

Comment: Try select by attribute using char_length function. If it works use query with your search cursor. For v 10 I suggest much easier to use da.SearchCursor

Comment: Use arcpy.da.SearchCursor -- much faster and more Pythonic

Answer (score 2):

For the old style cursor that you are using I would use this code:

```
import arcpy

tabla="C:/Users/jaguero/Desktop/validacion tabla/Valid.gdb/Predios"

rows=arcpy.SearchCursor(tabla)

for row in rows:
    if len(row.PRM_IDENTIFICA) != 14: #new code
        print len(row.PRM_IDENTIFICA)

del row,rows
```

However, I strongly recommend using Data Access cursors if you are using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop or later.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simple `if` statement to skip values that equal 14.

```
import arcpy

tabla="C:/Users/jaguero/Desktop/validacion tabla/Valid.gdb/Predios"

rows=arcpy.SearchCursor(tabla)

row=rows.next()

while row:

if len(row.PRM_IDENTIFICA) != 14: #new code
    print len(row.PRM_IDENTIFICA)

row=rows.next()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a layer (**shapefile**) with 37 features in it sitting on the top of my Table of Content. It has **text** field "NAME". Every odd record populated by 3 characters long string, other records populated by 2 characters long string.

I tested if CHAR_LENGTH function is valid one for query definition using this script:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0]
table=arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(layer,"NAME")
arcpy.AddMessage(len(table))
table=arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(layer,"NAME",r'CHAR_LENGTH("NAME")=3')
arcpy.AddMessage(len(table))
```

Output:

- Running script Script4...
- 37
- 19
- Completed script Script4...

It means that function can be used in cursor(s) definition queries

**PERFORMACE TEST**
using:

```
try: arcpy
except: import arcpy
import time
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0]
n=25000

t0=time.time()
for i in range(n):
    table=[]
    for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer,"NAME"):
        if len(row[0])==3:table.append(row)
arcpy.AddMessage ('%i seconds for iterations' %(time.time()-t0))

t0=time.time()
for i in range(n):
    table=[row for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer,"NAME",r'CHAR_LENGTH("NAME")=3')]
arcpy.AddMessage ('%i seconds for cursor' %(time.time()-t0))

t0=time.time()
for i in range(n):
    table=arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(layer,"NAME",r'CHAR_LENGTH("NAME")=3')
arcpy.AddMessage ('%i seconds for numpy' %(time.time()-t0))
```

On the same dataset and my out of date home PC

- 22 seconds for iterations
- 24 seconds for cursor
- 25 seconds for numpy

I admit defeat, query imposed on dataset works slower than simple filter during iterations. Makes it look smart though...

Comment: This may be right, but I don't have time to test.  However, I think it departs too much from the workflow being asked about to be of much use as an answer to this question.  If you were showing how to use CHAR_LENGTH with a cursor then I would be more interested in testing it but the inclusion of `arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray` just seems out of place when looking for an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) aligned to the question.

Comment: SearchCursor is identical to table.., the only difference being it works faster and faster unable to deal with geometry field

Comment: I think some performance timing between using this method to print the results and the same results from arcpy.da.SearchCursor() on a million rows would be interesting. If there is s big gap in favour of your method then it could make a more compelling case to use it.

Comment: Well, to me the essence of Q is about ability to use string manipulation function in search cursor. My test proves it is possible. As far as timing goes I wouldn't use table method on 1 mil records due to memory concerns. I ll use above script see which one is faster by repeat readings